# Adding a drop shadow to NSString text in a drawRect: method without using UILabel

Tags: ios, uiview, nsstring, drawrect, dropshadow

I'd like to add a drop shadow to text drawn using the iOS supplied `NSString (UIStringDrawing)` category method:

```
- (CGSize)drawAtPoint:(CGPoint)point forWidth:(CGFloat)width 
             withFont:(UIFont *)font minFontSize:(CGFloat)minFontSize 
       actualFontSize:(CGFloat *)actualFontSize 
        lineBreakMode:(UILineBreakMode)lineBreakMode
   baselineAdjustment:(UIBaselineAdjustment)baselineAdjustment;
```

Clearly, there's no drop shadow option.

Yes, one could use a UILabel here and get drop shadow properties to set, but that wouldn't be as performant, since any UIView subclass (such as UILabel) wraps a CALayer object and is going to be heavier (performance wise).

Here's the context:

I'm doing custom drawing for a UITableViewCell subclass, implementing `drawRect:` on the table cell view instead of creating the table cell from a Nib file of composited UIView subclasses.

Compositing a bunch of UIView subclasses would defeat the purpose of trying to keep this lean and stay within 50-60 frames per second in table view scrolling performance.

I have tried drawing the string twice at a slight offset. This may turn out acceptable once I tweak the drop shadow color on the background color of the cell that I have going, but it seems rather kludgey. Certainly there's no drop shadow blur property like one gets with UILabel.

I searched for solutions and they either recommend UILabel usage (which I've dismissed per above, since I have about a dozen distinct textual elements getting composited on to the table cell view) or `CGContextSetShadow()`. The latter always seems to be suggested in the context of rectangular shapes, and not necessarily for attaching a shadow to the path of text drawn directly with the NSString `drawAtPoint...` method mentioned above. (I did try it, but it didn't seem to work (i.e. nothing changed); I'm new to Core Graphics drawing).

Suggestions?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It works fine for me with `CGContextSetShadow()`. Example:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect 
{
    NSString *string = @"Hello World!";

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetShadow(context, CGSizeMake(20.0f, 20.0f), 10.0f);

    [string drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(100.0f, 100.0f) withFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:36.0f]];
}
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks Ole! Prior, I think I had too high a blur value and a offset of just (1,1) and so I couldn't see it taking effect. As I'm new to this, the next challenge I had was turning off the shadow effect for subsequent drawings (I really just need to read the Quartz 2D guide systematically). However, I did fine success in using "CGContextSaveGState(context)" before the shadow effect is set and "CGContextRestoreGState(context)" after the NSString has done it's drawing. I'm all set!